# Split string based on a series of characters

Tags: php

I want to know how i can split a string in php based on a series of characters.
Like for example, i have a string as: a^b^^c^^^d^^^^e

Now how i can break this string into an array as: a,b,c,d,e ?
The php explode function does not seem to work here....

Please help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function:

```
$array = preg_split("/\^+/", $str);
```

Comment: Ah, I was somehow assuming that after putting it inside `[]` it's not necessary, similarly to parentheses.